# Access members of case class

Tags: java, scala, akka, instanceof, case-class

I have a case class defined in a scala companion object.

```
case class ResponseSuccess(resp: SMPPSubmitSMResp)
```

Which I send to an akka-actor (Java)

```
if(res.isRight) sender ! Backend.ResponseSuccess(sms.resp)
```

It is received like this, but I don't know how to extract the SMPPSubmitSMResp from the ResponseSuccess

```
} else if (msg instanceof Backend.ResponseSuccess) {
        SMPPSubmitSMResp packet = (SMPPSubmitSMResp) msg;
        someFunc(packet);
}
```

the error I get (i.e. the message is received) is:

```
Backend$ResponseSuccess cannot be cast to SMPPSubmitSMResp
```

Comment: You can do `msg.resp` to get the `SMPPSubmitSMResp` inside the `ResponseSuccess`.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
[error]    SMPPSubmitSMResp packet = (SMPPSubmitSMResp) msg.resp;
[error]                                                    ^
[error]   symbol:   variable resp
[error]   location: variable msg of type Object

Comment: You need to cast `msg` to `ResponseSuccess` first.

Comment: `((Backend.ResponseSuccess)msg).resp()`

Answer (score 3):

If you use Scala, good approach to use Scala [Pattern Matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html):

```
msg match {
  case ResponseSuccess(resp) => // do something
  case _ => // do something else
}
```

If you want use Java, you will get a lot of cases where you have to cast objects especially for akka, so you can implement some utility for yourself. [Something like this](https://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/towards-pattern-matching-in-java/)

Comment: The OP is asking how to do it in Java.

Comment: The main program is in Java, some of the modules that are added/changed are being (re)done in scala. We prefer Scala, but cannot just rewrite everything.